# Friends missing in result of Facebook's invitable_friends endpoint

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I am requesting  `invitable_friends` and `friends`. I have 223 friends on Facebook, but when I add the result of the two endpoints I only get 219 friends. Some of my friends are missing in the result of the `invitable_friends` endpoint.

This is how I request the two endpoints:

**invitable_friends:**

```
FBRequest *friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/me/invitable_friends?fields=name,picture.width(%d).height(%d)", imageSizeInPixels, imageSizeInPixels]];
[friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary* result, NSError *error) {

    NSArray* friends = [result objectForKey:@"data"]; //201 objects
}];
```

**friends**:

```
FBRequest *friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/me/friends?fields=name,picture.width(%d).height(%d)", imageSizeInPixels, imageSizeInPixels]];
[friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              NSDictionary* result,
                                              NSError *error) {        
    NSArray* friends = [result objectForKey:@"data"]; //18 objects
}];
```

What can cause this? Is it possible for users to set privacy settings, such that I cannot request them in `invitable_friends`? Or am I requesting `invitable_friends` in a way that may leave out some of my friends?

I have tried reading through the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/invitable-friends/v2.2), but haven't found any explanation.

Comment: What do you get in the `summary->total_count` field when you request [`/me/friends`](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Ffriends&version=v2.2)? If that shows only 219 as well, then the difference is likely to be explained by those “missing” four friends having disabled all app access completely in their settings, which makes them “invisible” to any 3rd party app in every way.

Comment: I get 223: `"summary": {"total_count": 223}`

Comment: Perhaps those four friends are already users of your app then?

Comment: No, because  `201 + 18 != 223`. The 18 are the ones using the app. And I know for sure, that at least one of the 4 people, have never used the app.

Answer (score 0):

The summary->total_count is the number of friends you have on Facebook (regardless of whether they have Platform on or off).

The invitable_friends count should be

```
TOTAL_FRIENDS - FRIENDS_WITH_APP_INSTALLED - FRIENDS_WITH_PLATFORM_OFF
```

since you won't be able to invite them anyways.

Comment: What do you mean by "platform on or off". Is that a setting on Facebook somewhere? I would like to turn it off for debug purposes.

Comment: If you're logging in to Facebook, go to https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications, and click on the "Edit" button in the "Apps, Websites and Plugins" section.